# MySQL update using multiple INs

Tags: php, mysql

I am simply trying to verify if this is the best method using this particular UPDATE query.

Using an UPDATE with multiple IN clauses that looks like this:

```
UPDATE table_main
SET complete = 'Y',
WHERE booking IN ('book123', 'book124', 'book125') 
AND quote IN ('quote1', 'quote2', 'quote3') 
AND line IN ('line1', 'line2', 'line3')
```

The table looks like this:

```
| BOOKING | QUOTE | LINE | COMPLETE |
-------------------------------------
|book123  |quote1 |line1 |    N     |
-------------------------------------
|book124  |quote2 |line2 |    N     |
-------------------------------------
|book125  |quote3 |line3 |    N     |
-------------------------------------
|book123  |quote1 |line4 |    N     |
```

Why there is no ID column, I do not know.  There are primary keys on BOOKING and QUOTE. If you'll notice in the table, there are 2 entries of book123, quote1 with different lines.  This is just so you can get a feel of how the table works.

The `UPDATE` query will update all of the records above except for the last one with line = line4.

After running the query, it seems to work fine.

My question is, using that particular `UPDATE` query with the `IN` clause, does anyone foresee any problems it could possibly have?  Is there a better way to update multiple records?

I was thinking I could run a separate query for each booking/quote combo, but I figured that would tax the server unnecessarily.

I also thought about adding an ID column, but then I would have to update several other tables if I did that.

Comment: Your query also looks fine to me.  I can think of a way of shortening the `WHERE` clause use `REGEXP`, but that's unnecessary, and would leave the code harder to read IMO.  You might want to post this to our sister site Code Review Stack Exchange.

Comment: I was unaware of Code Review Stack Exchange.  Thank you for that info.

Comment: I can see a potential problem down the road.  Your update logic could change such that you wouldn't have just three `IN` clauses, you might need something way uglier than that.  But I can only speculate on how that would happen without knowing your data.

Comment: Any chance you could elaborate more on how I wouldn't have just three IN clauses?  In the end, had an ID field been created, this would save me the headache I'm having now.

Comment: Well, let's say that you might want logic that doesn't required ANDing together those `IN` clauses.  Then it could get unwieldy.

Comment: Understood.  I appreciate your input.  Thank you.